# Правильно ли я создаю структуру папок?

Tags: reactjs, структуры

Создал такую структуру папок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня будет одна страница Главная, на ней изначально будет поиск, после клика на кнопку поиска я буду менять на компонент `Products` и в этом компоненте у меня будет фильтр и список товаров. `Product` - сама наша одна карточка. `Filter` - фильтр товаров. `Products` - в нем я буду выводить Filter, Product.

Правильно ли я создал структуру или все же нужно создать еще `ProductList` и в нем выводить список товаров, а потом просто этот список выводить в Products?

Comment: + Я хочу сделать еще кнопку "Вернуться к поиску" для этой кнопки так же нужно создать новую папку?)